In MAUI How to display a SVG image that is not on the file system
I have a class with all the flags for each country. This is a normal C# class and you can see the source code on GitHub. Now, I have my .NET8 MAUI application and I want to display an SVG image from this class.
I created a SKCanvasView and I passed the SVG string to it. To simplify the example, I add the code of the flag in the OnPaintSurface
private SKSurface surface;
private SKCanvas canvas;
private SKSvg Svg { get; }

protected override void OnPaintSurface(SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs e)
{
    info = e.Info;
    surface = e.Surface;
    Canvas = surface.Canvas;
    Canvas.Clear();

    byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(SVGFlags.lgbt_1);
    using var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
    Svg.Load(stream);

    canvas.DrawPicture(Svg.Picture);
}

The result is the following:

In this case, I wanted to show the LGBT flag but I get only the top left corner of it.
The SVG starts with
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='75' height='75' 
     viewBox='0 0 75 75'>
<!-- full SVG -->
</svg>

Do I have to apply some sort of zoom to the SVG? If yes, how?

Does this answer your question? SkiaSharp SVG image not filling screen correctly

What nuget packages did you use and what the .net version did your project target? I try to test your code but the SKCanvasView show nothing. In addition, I create a new svg file with <svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='75' height='75'       viewBox='0 0 75 75'> and the string in the c# class. It will be cut off when I open the svg file in the browser. You can try to make the SVG start with <svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' > and test again.

That server side file is 5 Megabyte, flagmeister.github.io does all flags with one 32 Kilobyte Web Component Client side

What using do I need to get SKSvg known ?
